# An example of a regular normal space which is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

In the book Munkres they give an example of a regular space which is not Hausdorff: indiscrete topology on a two point sets. I understand that it is not Hausdorff but I am not sure how to prove that the singletons are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither regularity not normality requires singletons to be closed.  The point of this example is that  these properties, which speak of closed sets, hold almost by vacuity since there are so few closed sets.

---

Edit: take a set with two points, say $X=\{a,b\}$, with the indiscrete topology, namely  $\mathscr T =\{X,\emptyset\}$.

Then the singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are not closed because their complements are not open.  Therefore $X$ is not Hausdorff.

Nevertheless $X$ is normal.  Indeed, given two disjoint closed subsets ... what could be two disjoint closed subsets? ... well, there are very few choices, namely

1. $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$,
2. $\emptyset$ and $X$,
3. $X$ and $\emptyset$,

and in each case it is easy to find two disjoint open sets respectively containing them.

This proves normality and regularity is similar.

Comment: It's not clear . The singletons are closed right in the example?